# How to move all special characters to the end of the string in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to filter all non-alphanumeric characters to the end of the strings. I am having a hard time with the regex since I don't know where the special characters we be. Here are a couple of simple examples.

```
hello*there*this*is*a*str*ing*with*asterisks
and&this&is&a&str&ing&&with&ampersands&in&i&t
one%mo%refor%good%mea%sure%I%think%you%get%it
```

How would I go about sliding all the special characters to the end of the string?

Here is what I tried, but I didn't get anything.

```
re.compile(r'(.+?)(\**)')
r.sub(r'\1\2', string)
```

**Edit:**

Expected output for the first string would be:

```
hellotherethisisastringwithasterisks********
```

Comment: Use some String manipulation functions instead of regex.

Comment: @anubhava Updated the question with a sample output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no need for regex here. Just use `str.isalpha` and build up two lists, then join them:

```
strings = ['hello*there*this*is*a*str*ing*with*asterisks',
'and&this&is&a&str&ing&&with&ampersands&in&i&t',
'one%mo%refor%good%mea%sure%I%think%you%get%it']
for s in strings:
    a = []
    b = []
    for c in s:
        if c.isalpha():
            a.append(c)
        else:
            b.append(c)
    print(''.join(a+b))
```

Result:

```
hellotherethisisastringwithasterisks********
andthisisastringwithampersandsinit&&&&&&&&&&&
onemoreforgoodmeasureIthinkyougetit%%%%%%%%%%
```

Alternative `print()` call for Python 3.5 and higher:

```
print(*a, *b, sep='')
```

Comment: I looked through the Python string page and isalpha wasn't listed under the common operations or on the main string library page. I would have never thought to look for it specifically. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my proposed solution for this with regex:

```
import re

def move_nonalpha(string,char):
     pattern = "\\"+char
     char_list = re.findall(pattern,string)
     if len(char_list)>0:
         items = re.split(pattern,string)
         if len(items)>0:
             return ''.join(items)+''.join(char_list)
```

Usage:

```
string = "hello*there*this*is*a*str*ing*with*asterisks"
print (move_nonalpha(string,"*"))
```

Gives me output:

```
hellotherethisisastringwithasterisks********
```

I tried with your other input patterns as well and it's working. Hope it'll help.

Comment: Ya, the regex solution isn't nearly as elegant as using string manipulation. I thought it would have been the other way around, as that has usually been my experience.